# Updating child views position into parent view at runtime

Tags: android, view, position

I've got a FrameLayout with TextView children and I'd like to change the position of the TextViews at runtime (in onSensorChanged(), so several time per seconds). There is no setPosition(...), so how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `View.layout(int,int,int,int)` method.
[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) says:

```
public void layout (int l, int t, int r, int b)

Since: API Level 1
Assign a size and position to a view and all of its descendants
This is the second phase of the layout mechanism. (The first is measuring).  
In this phase, each parent calls layout on all of its children to position them.  
This is typically done using the child measurements that were stored  
in the measure pass().
```

Comment: In onSensorChanged I tried `view.layout(x,y,x+view.getWidth(),y+view.getHeight());` for each view, where x and y are the new coordinates, and the views are not even shown...

Comment: note that x and y relative to parent. Make sure that your view width and height aren't zeroes.

Comment: They're not... When layout is called, l, t, r and b are correct. But the views are not shown. I tried to invalidate() the parent and it does not change anything...

Comment: I've also got a surfaceview in my layout, and when I remove it it works correctly. I'm going to ask a new question.

Comment: i dont know why so behaviour appears =(. When i call `layout` method in my `onTouchEvent` method it works fine

Answer (score 0):

`FrameLayout` isn't good for doing this sort of thing, with `RelativeLayout` you can do the following:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();

layoutParams.leftMargin = x;
layoutParams.topMargin = y;

child.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```